# Does Removing Audio From a Video File Reduce Its Size?

Tags: video, video-capture, video-processing

I am working on a service where we take comparatively large video files (through user uploads) and process the frames that make up it.  We do not need the audio associated with the video.

I want to minimize the file size of the video the user uploads.  Does stripping the audio out on the client side reduce a video's size?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Of course. Audio is information. Less information, less size...

An easy way to "measure" it using ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:0 -c:v copy only_video.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:1 -c:a copy only_audio.mp4
```

This way, you can separate the video and audio in 2 different files without any reencoding. So you can have an idea of how much bytes you save on your case. Of couse. Different videos have different bitrates, so the proportion will be according to the videos you are working with.

**OBS:** MAYBE your streams are inverted... so `-map 0:0` may be changed to `-map 0:1` for video and the `-map 0:1` -> `-map 0:0` for audio. But usually 0 = video and 1 = audio.

Comment: Do you have any details related to file size reduced when audio is taken out?

Comment: sure, you can test by your own... I will update the answer on how to do that ;-)